# Start an Android Test from an Intent (or from SL4A)?

Tags: android, automation, android-testing, sl4a

I'd like to run some android tests but I want to scedule or delay the execution of these tests. I'm trying to do this from SL4A. The idea is to install SL4A start the server from my laptop, run a special python script that will sleep for about 20 seconds then wakeup and launch the tests. I am performing some rather involved automation that requires my tests be run after I install them and disconnect the USB cable. I know I can issue intents from SL4A but I'm looking for the equivalent of:

```
adb shell am instrument \
     -e class MyInstrumentationTestCase \
     -w MyInstrumentationTestRunner
```

Can this be done via intent? Should I send a broadcast or use the start activity functions?

I've tried running a system command directly on the device from Python with this script but I get a "permission denied" error:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["am", "instrument", "-e", "class", "com.example.android.app.test.TestContactList", "-w", "com.example.app.test/com.zutubi.android.junitreport.JUnitReportTestRunner"])
```

**UPDATE**
I've also tried using os.system to run the command (see below modifications) and this gives a different error: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libanroid_runtime.so" needed by "app_process"; caused by so info_relocate(linker.cpp:975): cannot locate symbol " sqlite3_stmt_readonly" referenced by "lib android_runtime.so"...CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE

```
import os
#from subprocess import call
#call(["am", "instrument", "-e", "class", "com.example.android.app.test.TestContactList", "-w", "com.example.android.app.test/com.zutubi.android.junitreport.JUnitReportTestRunner"])
os.system('echo "Running tests"')
os.system('am instrument -e class com.example.android.app.test.TestContactList -w com.example.android.app.test/com.zutubi.android.junitreport.JUnitReportTestRunner')
```

What are any other options?

Answer (score 1):

I have the following function, which will launch any SL4A script from within a Python SL4A script, as a separate process. You can not use `subprocess` for this type of thing.

You may be able to deduce what you need from this.

```
from android import Android
droid = Android()

def launch_script(path, visible=False):

    visibilty   = 'FORE' if visible else 'BACK'
    activity    = 'com.googlecode.android_scripting.action.LAUNCH_{0}GROUND_SCRIPT'.format(visibilty)
    extras      = {'com.googlecode.android_scripting.extra.SCRIPT_PATH': path}
    packagename = 'com.googlecode.android_scripting'
    classname   = 'com.googlecode.android_scripting.activity.ScriptingLayerServiceLauncher'
    intent      = droid.makeIntent(activity, None, None, extras, None, packagename, classname).result
    droid.startActivityIntent(intent)
```

Comment: Interesting. So you're saying that you cannot use subprocess from SL4A on device? What I am attempting to do is launch an Android unit test suite programmatically after a small delay (15-20 seconds). While startActivity() would work for "applications" there is no command to startInstrumentation() from SL4A. I've downloaded source and planned to add it however the build system is rather involved so I gave up.

Comment: You may be able to use subprocess on a rooted device. To be honest, I'm really unsure about that, but I've never seen anyone use subprocess in SL4A in cases where that'd be the obvious thing to do in Python. You can access sensors and so on from SL4A directly though. What are you trying to do? A script that gathers sensor readings over time should be easy enough to do just using the `android.Android` object.

Comment: I'm merely trying to launch a suite of Android test cases after a small delay (15-20seconds) from Python. I'm going to try os.system instead to see if that works.

Comment: I just trieid both running the "am instrument..." cmd both interactively from adb shell and programmatically from sl4a Python using os.system. It works find in the interactive shell, however attempting to launch it from Python via os.system I get a strange error: soinfo_link_image(linker.cpp:1635): could not load library "libanroid_runtime.so" needed by "app_process"; caused by so info_relocate(linker.cpp:975): cannot locate symbol " sqlite3_stmt_readonly" referenced by "lib android_runtime.so"...CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE

Comment: I'm not sure what to suggest. I'll look into it though. I like to see SL4A making this kind of thing easy, where here it's just being a pain. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyhow! Yes, this is sort of an edge case. I can't imagine too many people wanting to launch an Android test suite from a script. If I could at least figure out how to build the project without reading a 15 step manual then I could probably add the support I needed.